# Java Strange error while running the program

Tags: java, runtime-error

I ran into a strange error. I don't know why it occurs. It doesn't crash the program, it just returns some strange messages to the console. It usually shows up when the program is running for the first time (I mean: the method where the error occurs is executed the first time). I have never experienced anything like this, I will be grateful for your help!

Error message in console:

```
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/WARN]: Nag author(s): '[Adixe]' of 'DiscordUtils' about their usage of System.out/err.print. Please use your plugin's logger instead (JavaPlugin#getLogger).
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
[20:19:01] [Craft Scheduler Thread - 696 - DiscordUtils/ERROR]: [DiscordUtils] [STDERR] Could not detect EOL Linux Distribution because of the following error: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
```

Problematic code fragment:

```java
ArrayList<byte[]> userBytes = userAudioData.getBytes();

if (userBytes.size() <=
        settings.getInt("MaxLength") * 50) {
    User user = userAudioData.getUser();

    int length = 0;

    for (byte[] bytes : userBytes) {
        length += bytes.length;
    }

    byte[] decodedData = new byte[length];

    int i = 0;

    for (byte[] bytes : userBytes) {
        for (byte sampleByte : bytes) {
            decodedData[i++] = sampleByte;
        }
    }

    File file = new File(instance.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/temp/" + user.getId() + ".wav");

    try {
        AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedData),
                        AudioReceiveHandler.OUTPUT_FORMAT, decodedData.length),
                AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    //By deduction I figured out that an error could appear on this line:
    SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
            settings.getString("ApiKey"),
            settings.getString("ApiRegion"));

    speechConfig.setSpeechRecognitionLanguage(
            settings.getString("Language"));

    AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(file.getAbsolutePath());

    SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    try {
        SpeechRecognitionResult result = recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync().get();

        Logger.info("RECOGNIZED: " + result.getText());

        if (!file.delete())
            Logger.warn("Cannot delete temporary file " + file.getName() + ".");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

userAudioData.clear();
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It would help if you told us what DiscordUtils package you're using and is throwing the error or how you determined that part of the code is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated invocations of array's `length` seem to occur in the loop:

```java
    for (byte[] bytes : userBytes) {
        length += bytes.length;
    }
```

It is likely that the list `userBytes` contains some `null` values therefore you should just add a null check when calculating the `length` and populating `decodedData`:

```
    for (byte[] bytes : userBytes) {
        if (null != bytes) {
            length += bytes.length;
        }
    }

    byte[] decodedData = new byte[length];

    int i = 0;

    for (byte[] bytes : userBytes) {
        if (null != bytes) {
            for (byte sampleByte : bytes) {
                decodedData[i++] = sampleByte;
            }
        }
    }
```